# OpenLayers 6 - Overlay positioning does not working

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I am facing the following issue in my OpenLayers application (- based on Angular):

I have a map which is confined only to Austria.
I created a button what the user can change layer with.

The functionality works fine but the modal overlay gets always in the middle of my page which is not visible at all because it is zoomed to the desired country:

[image]

I always have to zoom out first to see my modal window.

This is my code:

```
onChangeLayer() {
    this.showLayerModel = true;

    const container = document.getElementById('popup-layer');
    const closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer-layer');

    /**
    * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
    */
    const overlay = new Overlay({
        element: container,
    });

    overlay.setPosition([14.12456, 47.59397]);

    this.map.addOverlay(overlay);

    var object = (document.getElementById("line") as HTMLTextAreaElement);

    const layerCollection = this.map.getLayers().getArray();

    object.addEventListener("change", function () {
        layerCollection.forEach((e) => {
            e.setVisible(object.value === e.get('title'))
        });
    });

    closer.onclick = function () {
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    }
}
```

It does not matter what I give as overlay.setPosition(), the modal is always in the middle of the screen.

```
<button type="button" class="roundedButton" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;" (click)="onChangeLayer()">
    Change layer
</button>
<div [hidden]="!showLayerModel" id="popup-layer" class="modal">
    <a href="#" id="popup-closer-layer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
    <div>
        <select id="line">
            <option value="first">First option</option>
            <option value="second">Second option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


.modal {
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
bottom: 12px;
left: -50px;
min-width: 280px;
```

}

Any ideas?

Please note, that the switching functionality works like a charm.

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

---

Answer of Mike below just worked fine!

Another point of view:

How can I get my model always in the middle of the given viewport?

I have the following code snippet:

```
var extent = this.map.getView().calculateExtent(this.map.getSize());
    var extent = transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

    console.log(extent);

    overlay.setPosition(fromLonLat(extent)), this.map.getView().getProjection();


    this.map.addOverlay(overlay);
```

But this positions the modal in the bottom right corner of the given view:

[image]

Ach, ok.
Answer here is:

```
overlay.setPosition(this.map.getView().getCenter());
```

Comment: overlay.setPosition coordinates should be in view projection.  Is the view in EPSG:4326?

Comment: @mike thanks for your answer! I do not really get it, I am relative new with OL. I think this is rather EPSG:3857.

Comment: Try `overlay.setPosition(fromLonLat([14.12456, 47.59397], map.getView().getProjection()));` which should work for any projection.

Comment: @mike, thanks a lot, it worked! I have added another thought to my question, you might could check that one too for me?

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I display a list of customers on the map.
After spending 1 day on this problem
I found this solution :

```
overlay.setPosition(features[index].getGeometry().getCoordinates(), map.getView().getProjection());
```

And

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([customer.Longitude, customer.Latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

[image]